# Integrate github with Openshift

Tags: github, openshift

I think this question has already been asked but i am still not clear about it.

This is my question:

I already have a Github Account with an existing repo. I want to start a project on Openshift, but Openshift creates it's own git repo in cloud and i have no access to it just like i have to my existing Github account. So what i want to do is integrate existing Github account with Openshift so that openshift will not use it's own git repo.

I think you have understood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift needs to use it's own git repo. That's how you update your Openshift app.  From there you create/add a remote (ex. Github) if you want to update that also.

There are examples on how to merge your Github repo to Openshift to start.  You will have to google it because I don't have the link handy now.  Sorry.

Comment: you mean to say that first i clone my personal repo, make changes then merge it with openshift and push it. But still two repo are being maintained but i only want single

Comment: The Openshift repo is the master repo. If you also want a copy of the repo on Github you will have to create a remote there also.   You will have to push /update both separately.

Comment: but i want my personal github repo to be the master repo of openshift

Comment: Once you create the Openshift repo merge your Github repo to it. Openshift has a step by step on how to do this. Google it.

Comment: Openshift has to be master as far as I know

Comment: so this means there is no way to move openshift's git repo to any other github account

Comment: No.  You can create a remote repo from the master Openshift repo.  That's how I push my Openshift repo to Github.

Comment: pushing to github will automatically reflect in openshift's git?

Comment: No.  You push master to Openshift then you push to your remote at Github.  You need to do it twice.

Comment: i have tried your method but i want to push only once and too to github. i think it is not possible.